# Usager_matrice = int(matrice)[id_usager]

Tags: python, attributes, int

I don't know where to look to correct the INT error. It's quite a large program.

I have error on my def recommander. Python told me INT error ....

Program have 3 files:

1st:

```
import tp2_utils

**def ouvrir_et_lire_fichier_reseau():**

    descripteur_fichier = tp2_utils.ouvrir_fichier()
    # La première ligne du fichier contient le nombre total d'usagers
    nb_usagers = int(descripteur_fichier.readline())
    print("Le réseau contient {} usagers".format(nb_usagers))

    # Création d'un réseau vide (c-a-d une liste de listes vides)
    reseau = []
    for i in range(nb_usagers):
        reseau.append([])

    # Chaque ligne du fichier (sauf la première) contient un coupe "d'amis"
    for ligne in descripteur_fichier.readlines():
        couple_usagers = ligne.split(' ')
        id_usager_1 = int(couple_usagers[0])
        id_usager_2 = int(couple_usagers[1])
        reseau[id_usager_1].append(id_usager_2)
        reseau[id_usager_2].append(id_usager_1)

    # Fermeture du fichier
    descripteur_fichier.close()
    print("Lecture du fichier terminé.")

    return reseau


**def trouver_nombre_elements_communs_entre_listes(liste1, liste2):**                   
    compteur_amis_commun = 0
    for element in liste1:
        if element in liste2:
            compteur_amis_commun = compteur_amis_commun + 1
    return compteur_amis_commun


**def calculer_scores_similarite(reseau):**
    """ Ne pas oublier les docstring"""
    n = len(reseau)
    matrice_similarite = "initialiser_matrice_carre(n)"
    liste1 = []
    liste2 = []
    compteur_liste1 = 0
    compteur_liste2 = 0

    for element_liste1 in reseau:
        liste1 = element_liste1
        for element_liste2 in reseau:
            liste2 = element_liste2
            compteur_amis_commun = trouver_nombre_elements_communs_entre_listes(liste1, liste2)
            matrice_similarite:[compteur_liste1][compteur_liste2] = compteur_amis_commun
            compteur_liste2 = compteur_liste2 + 1
        compteur_liste1 = compteur_liste1 + 1
        compteur_liste2 = 0

    return matrice_similarite



**def recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite):**
    """ Ne pas oublier la docstring"""
    usager_matrice = matrice_similarite[id_usager]
    ami_recommande = matrice_similarite.index(max(usager_matrice))
    max_value = max(matrice_similarite.index(usager_matrice))

    if ami_recommande == id_usager:
        max_value = max_value - 1

    ami_recommande = matrice_similarite.index(max_value)

    while True:
        if ami_recommande == reseau.index (ami_recommande):
            ami_recommande = reseau.index (max_value, ami_recommande + 1)
            return True

        return ami_recommande
```

The second files :

```
**def ouvrir_fichier():**
    """
    Demande à l'utilisateur un nom de fichier et ouvre ce fichier.

    Returns:
        descripteur_fichier: le descripteur du fichier ouvert

    """

    # On répète la boucle tant que l'usager n'a pas entré un nom de ficher valide
    while True:
        try:
            nom_fichier = input('Veuillez entrer le nom du fichier: ')
            descripteur_fichier = open(nom_fichier, 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Le fichier n'existe pas. Recommencez!")
            continue
        break

    return descripteur_fichier


**def initialiser_matrice_carre(n):**
    """
    Crée une matrice de taille nxn, initialisée avec des zéros et retourne la matrice.
    Args:
        n (int): dimension de la matrice nxn
    Returns:
        matrice (list): matrice initialisée

    """
    matrice = []
    for ligne in range(n):  # pour chacune des lignes dans n
        matrice.append([])  # créer une ligne (liste) et l'initialiser à 0
        for colonne in range(n):
            matrice[ligne].append(0)  # ajouter un 0 pour chaque n colonne
    return matrice
```

And the last one :

```
import tp2_reseau_identifiants

print('--- Chargement du réseau (identifiants) ---')
reseau = tp2_reseau_identifiants.ouvrir_et_lire_fichier_reseau()
nb_usagers = len(reseau)

matrice = tp2_reseau_identifiants.calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
matrice_similarite = tp2_reseau_identifiants.calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)

fin_du_programme = False
while not fin_du_programme:
    id_usager = None

    while True:
        try:
            id_usager= int(input("Entrer l'id de l'usager pour lequel vous voulez une recommandation (entre 0 et {}):".format(nb_usagers-1) ))
        except ValueError:
            print("Vous devez entrer un nombre entier")
            continue

        break

    identifiant_valide = True
    if 0 <= id_usager <= 9:
        id_recommandation =(tp2_reseau_identifiants.recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice))
        print("Pour la personne {}, nous recommandons l'ami {}.".format(id_usager, id_recommandation) )

    else:
        print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", nb_usagers - 1, "inclusivement.\n")
```

And the error that I'm trying to fix:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-2-b61485ffdc41>", line 1, in <module>
        runfile('C:/Users/Fabien/Desktop/Tp2.1/programme_partie1.py', wdir='C:/Users/****/Desktop/Tp2.1')
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
        pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
        exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
      File "C:/Users/****/Desktop/Tp2.1/programme_partie1.py", line 25, in <module>
        tp2_reseau_identifiants.recommander (id_usager, reseau, matrice))
      File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Tp2.1\tp2_reseau_identifiants.py", line 80, in recommander
        usager_matrice = matrice.index(id_usager)
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide the full error output to make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Okey, I edited it